# How to replace a simple two turn loop, with two manual calls (tricky)

Tags: go, recursion

Here is the code: https://play.golang.org/p/Sizbc3uJt_c

I try to replace this simple loop

```
for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
    indent(space+"   ", c)
}
```

which produces

```
html
   head
   body
      a
         1
      a
         1
      div
         a
            2
         a
            3
```

When I try this

```
if n.FirstChild != nil {
    indent(space+"   ", n.FirstChild)
}
if n.FirstChild != nil && n.FirstChild.NextSibling != nil {
    indent(space+"   ", n.FirstChild.NextSibling)
}
```

the output is only half

```
html
   head
   body
      a
         1
      a
         1
```

And when I try this

```
if n.FirstChild != nil {
    indent(space+"   ", n.FirstChild)
}
if n.NextSibling != nil {
    indent(space+"   ", n.NextSibling)
}
```

the output is complete, but indent is different. The result is

```
html
   head
      body
         a
            1
            a
               1
               div
                  a
                     2
                     a
                        3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with the second group of code you suggested that has a weird indent, here is the solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader(`<a href="test1.html">1</a><a href="test1.html">1</a><div><a href="test2.html">2</a><a href="test3.html">3</a></div>`)
    doc, err := html.Parse(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    indent("", doc)
}

func indent(space string, n *html.Node) {
    fmt.Println(space, n.Data)

    if n.FirstChild != nil {
        indent(space+"   ", n.FirstChild)
    }
    if n.NextSibling != nil {
        indent(space, n.NextSibling)
    }
}
```

You just have to remove the extra `+"    "` for the indent call with `n.NextSibling` so that sibling nodes are not pushed out further than their previous siblings.

Comment: thanks, this works. (but still dont know how to use n.FirstChild.NextSibling. In the loop it works... maybe someday I'll get it ;))

Comment: Ok, I get it. https://play.golang.org/p/MRRQBww4mgd When using n.FirstChild.NextSibling, there might be more turns needed than two...